# Can you change which provider OracleConnection uses by default?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, system.data.oracleclient

I have an application that uses `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection` (yes I know this is obsolete) without specifying a provider. It appears to be using `MSDORA` by default. Can I change the provider without adding a provider on the connection string? eg in the app.config file or a machine wide setting?

Answer (score 0):

A more optimal option would be to use `ODP.NET`

To implement this, start by adding a reference to Oracle.DataAccess. Then, add the following two lines before your public declaration:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
```

This should allow you to use ODP.NET as follows:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=mysrc;User Id=id;Password=password;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open(); 
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "my query";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
label1.Text = dr.GetString(0); //Assuming the label already exists
conn.Dispose();
```

For more help, try following Oracle's official guide found [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm)